# Iteratively build up a vector based on clicked DataTable cells

Tags: r, datatable, shiny

I am trying to create a simple Karaoke queue app for a party. I have a DataTable that stores my Karaoke song collection. I would like to click on an item from the song list and have it added to a second DataTable which will be a queue. I would like subsequently clicked songs to be added to the queue table. However, my attempts at coding this result in the queue list not persisting. It only ever has one track in the list.

**How can I iteratively add elements to a vector using the clicked cells from a DataTable in shiny?**

**server.R**

```
queue <- list()

shinyServer(function(input, output) { 


  output$myTable <- renderDataTable({df}, options = list(bSortClasses = TRUE), callback = "function(table) {
    table.on('click.dt', 'tr', function() {
    Shiny.onInputChange('rows',
    table.row(this).data());
    });}")  


  # if data table is clicked, add to the queue
  observe({

    if (!is.null(input$rows)) {

      queue[[length(queue) + 1]] <- input$rows[3]

      dfq <- data.frame('FileName'=unlist(queue))

      output$queue <- renderDataTable({dfq}, callback = "function(table) {
        table.on('click.dt', 'tr', function() {
        Shiny.onInputChange('play',
        table.row(this).data());
        });}")
    }

  })

  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$play)){
      # grab the row from the data.frame
      selection <- df[df[,3] == input$play, ]

      play.music(selection)
    }

  })
})
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Karaoke!"),

  sidebarPanel(
    selDataTableOutput("queue")
  ),

  mainPanel(
    selDataTableOutput("myTable")
  )
)
)
```

Comment: should the title of this post be"iteratively build up vector based on clicked DataTable rows?". you are not actually using information about which cell was clicked, but rather taking the row from the input and then hardcoding it to use the third column

Answer (score 0):

You can store the vector into a file. When you start a new Shiny session, you define an empty file (e.g. cat("", nameFile.txt)). When you click on a cell, you append the new element to the file (e.g. cat(newElement, nameFile.txt, append = TRUE)) and you read the file as a vector (e.g. using read.table).